# JSON value from a clob field

Tags: json, clob

Select JSON value from a CLOB field

The header_info field

{

"Message-ID":"<SJ0P105MB0345C789105MB0345.MAMP999.PROD.LOOKIT.COM>"

}

I tried

select  JSON_VALUE('{header_info}', '$.Message-ID') from epres.mydata

I need to select the "Message-ID"
I get an error
ORA-40597: JSON path expression syntax error ('$.Message-ID')
JZN-00209: Unexpected characters after end of path
at position 10
40597. 00000 -  "JSON path expression syntax error ('%s')%s\nat position %s"
*Cause:    The specified JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) path expression
had invalid syntax and could not be parsed.
*Action:   Specify JSON path expression with the correct syntax.

using  Oracle Version 19.2.1.247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
'$."Message-ID"'
```

It does not like the embeded - , so you need to wrap it in double-quotes.

Comment: Thank you , that got rid of the error but I get null values

Answer (score 0):

If the json you have posted in this question is the same:

[image]

You got 2 random " there

That is the first thing i checked. Not sure if it will fix your problem, but if the json in invalid.. that would result in other things to fail of cours.

Comment: I cleaned it up for visibility , I'm only interested in the  "Message-ID"

Comment: {

"Message-ID":"<SJ0P105MB0345C789105MB0345.MAMP999.PROD.LOOKIT.COM>"

}